# Only charges through USB when screen is locked

Tags: charging, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G running 4.4.4.

When it's connected to a PC, it will only charge if the screen is locked: as soon as it's unlocked it will stop charging. In this situation, even if I lock the screen again it will not go back to charging.

When it's connected to the charger, it charges normally regardless of being unlocked or not.

What can be causing this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Is "What to do?" really your question? The obvious answer is "plug it into the charger when you want to charge it".

Comment: @DanHulme edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause is that your PC can't supply enough current over the USB connection to charge your phone while it's awake. Smartphones draw a lot of power these days, so their chargers use extensions to the USB standard to supply more power, so they can charge even while the phone is in use. Most PCs don't support these extensions, so they can't.

The solution is to use the charger to charge your phone. You can buy a Y-shaped USB cable which splits the power and data connections, so you can have it plugged into the PC and charger at once if need be. Some docking stations also have this ability.

Comment: A reset of the phone didn't solve the problem, so I guess that's it. Accepting (late) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is that this is done to protect the data on your phone. It can be unsafe to connect your phone's usb when unlocked. (usb condom)

Comment: Could you confirm/explain more about this? As far as I know, "USB condom" just prevents device's data being uploaded to host by disabling data-pins, but it doesn't seem to be intuitive to block charging if the phone is unlocked.